# JSON array access in freemarker

Tags: java, arrays, json, freemarker

I want to use JSON with freemarker. In ajax I got an JSON array. How can I pass this array to freemarker and iterate over elements? I know that I should use:

```
<#list clients?? as client>
```

but how to pass my JSON which is in format like below to this list?

```
{
    "clients": [{
        "name": "Franciszka",
        "surname": "Bialorusin",
        "totalPrice": 4256.0,
        "indentList": [{
            "date": 1309212000000,
            "price": 2305.0
        }, {
            "date": 1399759200000,
            "price": 1493.0
        }, {
            "date": 1281996000000,
            "price": 358.0
        }, {
            "date": 1406239200000,
            "price": 100.0
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Stanislaw",
        "surname": "Bieleninik",
        "totalPrice": 993.0,
        "indentList": [{
            "date": 1313272800000,
            "price": 979.0
        }, {
            "date": 1321052400000,
            "price": 14.0
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Renata",
        "surname": "Bieleninik",
        "totalPrice": 834.0,
        "indentList": [{
            "date": 1391122800000,
            "price": 392.0
        }, {
            "date": 1381096800000,
            "price": 389.0
        }, {
            "date": 1351029600000,
            "price": 45.0
        }, {
            "date": 1347919200000,
            "price": 8.0
        }]
    }]
}
```

EDIT: I'm digging and it looks that I should use jquery to build HTML. Is there any better solution?

Comment: You realise FreeMarker is tool which generates pages and AJAX is technically JavaScript to make the site interactive?
After a quick search this might help you: https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/web-scripts/json-array-evaluating-stringmodel-freemarker-10312014-0957

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two separate questions.  FreeMarker is a server-side templating language that is run just BEFORE the page is loaded.  AJAX (and JavaScript) is typically a client-side language (though more and more libraries like node are making the case for using JS server-side) that is run just AFTER the page is loaded, most commonly to handle events, animations, etc.

If your server code (i.e. Java) is making a request and receiving the JSON data, you can then pump that JSON data into FreeMarker to use the way you asked.

If instead you are making the request via client-side code, i.e. with AJAX, then the FreeMarker has already run so your only option is to use client-side code (jQuery, vanilla JavaScript, etc.) to do something with it.

I don't know what you are trying to do with the JSON response exactly, however one thing you might want to look into is how to use RESTful web services in your HTML (using something like Angular, for instance) as RESTful services are essentially returning a JSON object to some request.

If you give more information on what you are trying to accomplish, or what you know/have already tried, I would be more than happy to amend this answer to give you something concrete instead of theory. :)